# Shallow copying an array of class pointers

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

I am trying to finish a project.

In one part, I have to use a copy constructor to make a shallow copy of an array of pointers to two picture objects.

I don't understand how to complete this constructor:

```
#ifndef PICTURE_PAIR_H
#define PICTURE_PAIR_H

class Picture;                              // Forward declaration. Picture
                                            // is used in general constructor
class Picture_Pair
{
private:
  Picture* pp[2] {nullptr, nullptr};        // Pointers to the two Pictures
```

```
Picture_Pair::Picture_Pair(const Picture_Pair& pp)
{
  pp=pp.pp;
}
```

I know that `pp=pp.pp` is not right.  How do I fix this?

Comment: Copying pointers around quickly leads to losing track of ownership. You may want to start using STL already, like reference-counted shared pointers: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr

Comment: Naming a parameter the same as a member is a sure way to trouble.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want (for a shallow copy) is:

```
Picture_Pair::Picture_Pair(const Picture_Pair& copy_from)
{
    memcpy (pp, copy_from.pp, sizeof (pp));
}
```

This copies both pointers.

Note that naming the parameter `pp` hides the instance variable of the same name.

Comment: `std::copy(_n)()` would be the more correct and preferred solution in this situation, and the compiler can optimize it to the equivalent of `memcpy()` for trivially copyable types.

Answer (score 0):

Your `pp` memory is a raw C-style array holding 2 pointers.  You cannot assign a raw array directly to another raw array.  You need to copy the individual elements from one array to the other, eg:

```
Picture_Pair::Picture_Pair(const Picture_Pair& src)
{
  pp[0] = src.pp[0];
  pp[1] = src.pp[1];
}
```

Or:

```
Picture_Pair::Picture_Pair(const Picture_Pair& src)
{
  for(int i = 0; i < 2; ++i)
    pp[i] = src.pp[i];
}
```

Or:

```
#include <algorithm>

Picture_Pair::Picture_Pair(const Picture_Pair& src)
{
  std::copy(src.pp, src.pp+2, pp);
}
```

Or:

```
#include <algorithm>

Picture_Pair::Picture_Pair(const Picture_Pair& src)
{
  std::copy_n(src.pp, 2, pp);
}
```

However, you don't actually need to define a copy constructor or assignment operator for your `Picture_Pair` class, the default implementations will suffice to shallow-copy the array for you:

```
class Picture_Pair
{
private:
  Picture* pp[2]{nullptr, nullptr};
  ...
public:
  ...
  Picture_Pair(const Picture_Pair&) = default;
  ...
  Picture_Pair& operator=(const Picture_Pair&) = default;
  ...
};
```

Though, you are clearly using C++11 or later, so you should consider using a C++-style [`std::array`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) instead of a raw C-style array:

```
#include <array>

class Picture_Pair
{
private:
  std::array<Picture*, 2> pp{nullptr, nullptr};
  ...
public:
  ...
  Picture_Pair(const Picture_Pair&) = default;
  ...
  Picture_Pair& operator=(const Picture_Pair&) = default;
  ...
};
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I understand more how to use shallow copy for array now.